# rShiny Looping on ui filter conditions

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create a dashboard in rShiny which follow the following steps

1. Select a parameter
2. Filter data from a source table for this parameter
3. Create a list of this filtered data for one of the column
4. Iterate over this list to display graphs etc...
   I have tried various options for making this work but the communication between ui and server is not happening as expected

I have created a setup as below fot testing

```
library(shiny)
df_mtcars <- mtcars
df_mtcars <- cbind(CarName = rownames(df_mtcars), df_mtcars)
df_mtcars$CarName <- sub(" ", "_", df_mtcars$CarName)
```

select the number of gears
Find the cars with that number of gears
Create a list of these cars
Display the data for each of the car by using loop. Loop is needed as other output types like graphs can be latter added

```
simpUI <- function(id) {
    tagList(tableOutput(NS(id, "dat_output"))
            numericInput(NS(id, "GearNumber"), "Gear Numbers", 3),
            lapply(seq(1, length(v_lst_CarName), by = 1), function(i) {
                v_CarName = v_lst_CarName[i]
                v_obj_CarName = paste0('sp_cars_', v_CarName)
                tableOutput(NS(id, v_obj_CarName))
            }))
}

simpServer <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        output$dat_output <- renderTable(df_mtcars)
        v_lst_CarName <-
            reactive(df_mtcars[GearNumber == input$GearNumber]$CarName)
        for (v_CarName in v_lst_CarName)
            v_obj_CarName = paste0('sp_cars_', v_CarName)
        output$v_obj_CarName <- renderTable(v_obj_CarName)
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(simpUI("cars")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    simpServer("cars")
}
shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to do server side processing.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
df_mtcars <- mtcars
df_mtcars <- cbind(CarName = rownames(df_mtcars), df_mtcars)
df_mtcars$CarName <- sub(" ", "_", df_mtcars$CarName)

simpUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(tableOutput(ns("dat_output")),
          numericInput(ns("GearNumber"), "Gear Numbers", 3),
          uiOutput(ns("plotxy")),
          tableOutput(ns("v_obj_CarName")),
          verbatimTextOutput(ns("mylist")),
          plotOutput(ns("myplot"))
          )
}

simpServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    output$dat_output <- renderTable(head(df_mtcars))
    mydf <- reactive(df_mtcars[df_mtcars$gear == input$GearNumber,])
    v_lst_CarName <-  eventReactive(mydf(), {paste0("sp_cars_",mydf()$CarName)})
    
    output$plotxy <- renderUI({
      req(mydf())
      tagList(
        selectInput(ns("xvar"), label = "X-axis variable", choices = names(mydf()), selected=names(mydf())[2] ),
        selectInput(ns("yvar"), label = "Y-axis variable", choices = names(mydf()), selected=names(mydf())[5] )
      )
    })
    
    output$v_obj_CarName <- renderTable({mydf()})
    output$mylist <- renderPrint(list(v_lst_CarName() ))
    
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      req(input$xvar,input$yvar)
      ggplot(mydf(),aes(x=.data[[input$xvar]], y=.data[[input$yvar]])) + geom_point()
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(simpUI("cars")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  simpServer("cars")
}
shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution...but the present solution is like this 
```
Number of Cylinders (input field)
CarName1
CarName2
```
It would be helpful to get the solution like
```
Number of  Cylinders (input field) 
 CarName1 
  Analysis1 of this car1(some graphs etc..)
  Analysis2 of this car1
 CarName2 
  Analysis1 of this car2
  Analysis2 of this car2
```

Comment: This answer should help to move forward with your requirements.  There is no analysis being performed in your MRE.  I presume you can add that.

Comment: I have mentioned in the statement after the code..."Find the cars with that number of gears Create a list of these cars Display the data for each of the car by using loop. Loop is needed as other output types like graphs can be latter added"

Comment: Please note that we are only trying to help you if you are stuck.  You should perform whatever analysis you would like to display.

Comment: The problem I am trying to overcome is, say we have a large data set. Now we filter the data for one parameter.  There are multiple rows meeting this filter condition. This row has key column identifying row uniquely. Then each row has to be analyzed seperatly. This analysis could be from supplementary data etc...The solution provided by you reaches to the solution but misses the last part where it analyzes each row. Now coming to this statement, Filter the data by Number of Cylinders, (you did). Get the list of the cars of this cylinder count (you did).

Comment: But then you converted this list to data frame and showed using tableOutput. Need to loop this list and put some analysis, say print one row for now. This is what is needed here

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thanks YBS...it was nearly what I was looking for. Still the data is clubbed and not done for individual elements.  I have used your hints and applied ..can you suggest on the new post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72164931/rshiny-dashboard-by-looping-individual-values