# rshiny dashboard by looping individual values

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod, shinyapps

There is one dashboard where need to put the analysis for each of the element selected list.
I have created a setup as below fot testing
Need to generate the graphs for the date for the individual symbols as shown below.
The date is selected from the drop down. The list of symbols is provided by df_rep_date for this date.
This list is iterated and the graph is genereated for the symbols in the list as shown below.

```
install.packages('quantmod')
library('quantmod')

getSymbols("AAPL",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
getSymbols("MSFT",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
getSymbols("FB",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
getSymbols("ORCL",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
df_AAPL <- as.data.frame(AAPL)
df_AAPL$DATE <- index(AAPL)    
rownames(df_AAPL) <- NULL
names(df_AAPL) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
df_AAPL$SYMBOL <- 'AAPL'

df_MSFT <- as.data.frame(MSFT)
df_MSFT$DATE <- index(MSFT)    
rownames(df_MSFT) <- NULL
names(df_MSFT) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
df_MSFT$SYMBOL <- 'MSFT'

df_FB <- as.data.frame(FB)
df_FB$DATE <- index(FB)    
rownames(df_FB) <- NULL
names(df_FB) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
df_FB$SYMBOL <- 'FB'

df_ORCL <- as.data.frame(ORCL)
df_ORCL$DATE <- index(ORCL)    
rownames(df_ORCL) <- NULL
names(df_ORCL) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
df_ORCL$SYMBOL <- 'ORCL'

df_all <- rbind(df_AAPL, df_MSFT,df_FB,df_ORCL)
df_all[, c('SYMBOL','DATE','OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED')]
library(shiny)
#unique(df_all$DATE)
df_rep_date <- data.frame('RunDate'= character(),'ListStocks' = character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df_rep_date[1,] <-    c("2020-01-06", 'AAPL,MSFT')
df_rep_date[2,] <-    c("2021-01-04",'ORCL,AAPL')
df_rep_date[3,] <-    c("2022-01-04", 'FB,ORCL')
df_rep_date$RunDate <- as.Date(df_rep_date$RunDate)
v_lst_sel_dates <-c(df_rep_date$RunDate) 

func_1symb_plot <- function(p_symb){
    p_symb = 'AAPL'
    df_tmp_hist_dat = df_all[df_all$SYMBOL == p_symb,c("DATE" ,"OPEN","HIGH","LOW" ,"CLOSE","VOLUME" )]
    v_df_dly_dat_6mnth_xts <-  xts(df_tmp_hist_dat[, -1], order.by = df_tmp_hist_dat[, 1])
    v_grph_op <- candleChart( v_df_dly_dat_6mnth_xts,name = v_symb, type = "auto", up.col = "green", dn.col = "red",
                              theme = "white",plot = TRUE,TA = "addVo();addSMA(n = 1, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='black');
    addSMA(n = 7, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='gold'); addSMA(n = 14, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='brown');addMACD(); addBBands();addRSI();addOBV();")
    return(v_grph_op)}


simpUI <- function(id) {
    tagList(selectInput(NS(id, 'RunDate'), "Run Date", v_lst_sel_dates),
            textOutput(NS(id,'date_output')),
            textOutput(NS(id,'lst_symb_output')),
            textOutput(NS(id,'test_text'))),
    fluidPage( for (v_symb in lst_symb_output){
        renderTex('v_symb_name')
        plotOutput(v_symb)
    })
    
    
    simpServer <- function(id) {
        moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
            string <- reactive(input$RunDate)
            output$date_output <- renderText(string())
            v_lst_symbol <- reactive(df_rep_date[df_rep_date$RunDate == input$RunDate,]$ListStocks)
            output$lst_symb_output <- renderText(v_lst_symbol())
            for (v_symb in v_lst_symbol()){
                v_symb_name = paste0(v_symb, '_name')
                output$v_symb_name = v_symb
                output$v_symb <- renderPlot(func_1symb_plot(v_symb))
            }
        })
    }
    
    ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(simpUI("par1")))
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        simpServer("par1")
    }
    shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df_rep_date <- data.frame('RunDate'= character(),'ListStocks' = character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df_rep_date[1,] <-    c("2020-01-06", 'AAPL')
df_rep_date[2,] <-    c("2021-01-04", 'ORCL')
df_rep_date[3,] <-    c("2022-01-04", 'FB,MSFT')
#df_rep_date[4,] <-    c("2022-01-07", 'MSFT')
df_rep_date$RunDate <- as.Date(df_rep_date$RunDate)
v_lst_sel_dates <-c(df_rep_date$RunDate) 

func_1symb_plot <- function(p_symb){
  #p_symb = 'AAPL'
  df_tmp_hist_dat = df_all[df_all$SYMBOL == p_symb,c("DATE" ,"OPEN","HIGH","LOW" ,"CLOSE","VOLUME" )]
  v_df_dly_dat_6mnth_xts <-  xts(df_tmp_hist_dat[, -1], order.by = df_tmp_hist_dat[, 1])
  v_grph_op <- candleChart( v_df_dly_dat_6mnth_xts,name = p_symb, type = "auto", up.col = "green", dn.col = "red",
                            theme = "white",plot = TRUE,TA = "addVo();addSMA(n = 1, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='black');
    addSMA(n = 7, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='gold'); addSMA(n = 14, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='brown');addMACD(); addBBands();addRSI();addOBV();")
  return(v_grph_op)}


simpUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(selectInput(NS(id, 'RunDate'), "Run Date", v_lst_sel_dates),
          textOutput(NS(id,'date_output')),
          textOutput(NS(id,'lst_symb_output')),
          uiOutput(NS(id,"myplot"))
  )
}
  
simpServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    string <- reactive(input$RunDate)
    output$date_output <- renderText(string())
    v_lst_symbol <- reactive(df_rep_date[df_rep_date$RunDate == input$RunDate,]$ListStocks)
    output$lst_symb_output <- renderText(v_lst_symbol())
    observeEvent(input$RunDate, {
      print(v_lst_symbol())
      symbs <- read.table(text = v_lst_symbol(), sep = ",", colClasses = "character")
      print(symbs)
      lapply(symbs[1,], function(v_symb){
        v_symb_name = paste0(v_symb, '_name')
        output[[paste0(v_symb, '_name')]] = renderText(v_symb_name)
        output[[paste0(v_symb, '_plot')]] <- renderPlot(func_1symb_plot(v_symb))
      })
    })
    
    output$myplot <- renderUI({
      symbs <- read.table(text = v_lst_symbol(), sep = ",", colClasses = "character")
      tagList(
        lapply(symbs[1,], function(v_symb){
          id1 <- paste0(v_symb, '_name')
          id2 <- paste0(v_symb, '_plot')
          textOutput(ns(id1))
          plotOutput(ns(id2))
        })
      )
    })
    
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(simpUI("par1")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  simpServer("par1")
}
shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: When we change the date the list of the stocks changes, but the plot below the list is always for AAPL. Need to show the graphs for all the symbols in the list.  e.g. for 2020-01-06 the list shows AAPL and MSFT. So there should be two graphs. Similarly when 2021-01-04 is selected the list is ORCL, AAPL hence graphs for ORCL and AAPL should be shown. Presently it is showing only AAPL. Can you please look into this.

Comment: Presently one page is showing graph for 1 symbol. Looking for all the Symbols analysis for that particular date in one page. This will also be useful for the compartive study among symbols.

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thanks the code is providing the output as expected.